# Inserting values of Date type into a MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I have got a `JTable` implementing a `TableModel` interface. There are `ID` (primary key, auto-increment), `tbl_Date`, `Flat`, `Mobile`, `Food`, `Alcohol`, `Transport`, `Outdoor`, `Pauls_stuff`, `Income`, `Stuff` columns.

Every time I start the program, I want to get rows filled with data: `tbl_Date` until tommorow, everything else except ID, set to zeroes.

To be more clear, I will give an example. Let's say the last time I entered any data to database was on 2014-12-10. Today is 2014-12-14. I want the column `tbl_date` to be inserted with dates accordingly to tommorow's date (2014-12-15), and the rest of columns, except ID, to be set to zeroes.

I have the program producing the result I wanted. I wonder if it could be made somehow simpler and/or be optimised.

```
private static void createAndShowGUI() throws SQLException {
    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("TableWithBottomLine");
    TableWithBottomLine tbl = new TableWithBottomLine();        

    frame.addWindowListener(
            new WindowAdapter() {
                public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
                    try {                       
                        tbl.bottomLabel2.setText("Text");                           

                        String query ="SELECT f.tbl_Date FROM finance.fin f";       
                        ResultSet rs ;
                        Connection connection = TableWithBottomLine.getConnection();
                        Statement stmt = null;
                        stmt = connection.createStatement();
                        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                        rs.last();
                        // Let's get last date in tbl_Date row from database
                        tbl.lastDate = rs.getDate("tbl_Date");                      
                        long milliseconds = tbl.lastDate.getTime();
                        // Let's get current day
                        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
                        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
                        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                        cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
                        Long currentDate = cal.getTimeInMillis();                       

                        PreparedStatement pStmt = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT into finance.fin (tbl_Date, Flat, Mobile, Food, Alcohol, Transport, Outdoor, Pauls_stuff, Income, Stuff) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");                       
                        while (milliseconds < currentDate + 86400000)
                            {                                   
                                milliseconds = milliseconds + 86400000;

                                pStmt.setDate(1, getDateForInsertion(milliseconds));
                                pStmt.setFloat(2, 0.0f);
                                pStmt.setFloat(3, 0.0f);
                                pStmt.setFloat(4, 0.0f);
                                pStmt.setFloat(5, 0.0f);
                                pStmt.setFloat(6, 0.0f);
                                pStmt.setFloat(7, 0.0f);
                                pStmt.setFloat(8, 0.0f);
                                pStmt.setFloat(9, 0.0f);
                                pStmt.setFloat(10, 0.0f);                               

                                pStmt.addBatch();                       
                            }
                        pStmt.executeBatch(); 

                    } catch (Exception ee) {
                        ee.printStackTrace();
                    }                       
                } 
            }
        );        

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 //   frame.setContentPane(new TableWithBottomLine());
    frame.setContentPane(tbl);        
    new TableWithBottomLine().setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque        
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private static java.sql.Date getDateForInsertion(Long date) {
    Date tmp_date = new Date(date);  
    return new java.sql.Date(tmp_date.getTime());       
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a kind of pro but I know that you SHOULDN'T use String Combining on SQL queries, you should use [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).

Comment: good comment but the OP is using prepared statement. Or was this edited after the fact?

Answer (score 1):

As Visian Maya points out, use PreparedStatement. This is to avoid sql injection if nothing else.

Additionally it is considered good practice to close your resultsets and statements as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507440/must-jdbc-resultsets-and-statements-be-closed-separately-although-the-connection)

I would urge you to move the database connection logic to a separate method, if not a separate class. User interface classes are already very cluttered with a lot of UI code, it will not help readability to add db code to it. This will also help you reuse the db code, if you need to.

I would really not use java.sql.Date , instead create your own timestamp and store it as a long. see the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2306051/1197030) in this discussion for why

It looks like you want to get the highest date from your table.
Why not simply do that in sql (order by f.tbl_Date desc) and get the first result?

If you're never going to insert anything other than 0 into the query, you can pull the 0 values into the query.

```
while (...) {
    PreparedStatement pStmt = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT into finance.fin (tbl_Date, Flat, Mobile, Food, Alcohol, Transport, Outdoor, Pauls_stuff, Income, Stuff) values(?,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0)");   
    milliseconds = milliseconds + 86400000;
    pStmt.setDate(1, getDateForInsertion(milliseconds));
}
```

I would not use magic numbers. better make a

```
// somewhere at the top of your class: don't use magic numbers, use constants
public final static MILS_IN_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;


// and use this inside your loop
while (milliseconds < currentDate + MILS_IN_DAY) {                                   
    milliseconds = milliseconds + MILS_IN_DAY;
}
```